# How to embed JavaFX into eclipse rcp view

Tags: eclipse-rcp, javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to use JavaFX 2 from a simple eclipse view, but I am getting an

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Invalid URL for class:
>   bundleresource://435.fwk1827795025/com/sun/glass/utils/NativeLibLoader.class

After some investigation with JAD I have found out that NativeLibLoader has very interesting check:

```
if(!classUrlString.startsWith("jar:file:") || classUrlString.indexOf("!") == -1)
    throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError((new StringBuilder()).append("Invalid URL for class: ").append(classUrlString).toString());
```

Does this mean that javafx can't be used from OSGi bundle? Please prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to the JavaFX loader to be more [friendly with OSGI](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14479) are scheduled for the "Lombard" release (which is the [JavaFX 3.0 timeframe](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html), i.e. 2013). Until then, you may encounter issues working with JavaFX from an OSGI bundle.  Other OSGI related issues can be found by searching for OSGI in the [JavaFX Jira](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) (anybody can signup to view the bugs and issues listed there).  [Tom Schindl](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/), the creator of the [e(fx)clipse](http://www.efxclipse.org) plugin for JavaFX in Eclipse, would be the best contact point with experience in integrating JavaFX within Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I've just released a step by step tutorial how to create and export an Eclipse ViewPart that uses JavaFX 2.0. See http://www.efxclipse.org/trac/wiki/Tutorial3

Answer (score 0):

e(fx)clipse now has a wizard for this. Please take a look at:
http://www.efxclipse.org/trac/wiki/Tutorial2

You can quickly test your view with this hello world code:

```
public class MyViewPart extends FXViewPart {

    @Override
    protected Scene createFxScene() {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World!'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        return new Scene(root,300,200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setFxFocus() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls. follow this simple steps:

1. Create "Plugin from Existing JAR Archives" in Eclipse

   - add External ..jre/lib/jfxrt.jar (from jdk1.7)
   - click Target Platform "an OSGI framework" !
   - unselect "Unzip".
2. Click META-INF/MANIFEST.MF - in Runtime tab Export all
   Packages (with "Add").
3. Add the created "Fx_Osgi_Plugin" as required plugin
   in "Dependencies" tab for each plugin.xml.
4. In .product click "Add Required Plug-ins" in Dependencies tab.

Now plugins using Java-Fx have reference to an Osgi Java-Fx 
Version.