# Is there any way to load an Eclipse RCP plugin in javaFX?

Tags: javafx-2, eclipse-rcp

I saw a question in SO entitled "[How to embed JavaFX into eclipse rcp view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368925/how-to-embed-javafx-into-eclipse-rcp-view)". What I need is embedding an `Eclipse RCP` plugin in `javaFX` application. Is it possible? If yeah, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse plugins must be run inside an Eclipse RCP, they cannot be used in a ordinary Java / JavaFX program because they rely on the Eclipse / OSGi plugin infrastructure being initialized properly. Any plugin which has a UI will be using SWT.

Using [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) you can write an Eclipse e4 RCP using JavaFX for the UI. However plugins which use SWT for UI elements will still be a problem.

Comment: I'd like to add that embedding SWT in JavaFX will never ever work because JavaFX is a lightweight toolkit where as SWT is heavyweight - the other way round is naturally possible